# SDL 2, how use the event system and draw asynchronously

Tags: c++, sdl-2

You can only use the event system and the drawing system where it's initialized, and they have to be on the same thread,

wondering how if the polling system yields until an event is fired via

```
SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
```

how would I say, draw something at 60fps whilst still being able to take input from the user? I assume there's a timer event? Or are you not even supposed to use SDL_WaitEvent....

Wondering how I should structure my game

Comment: It sounds like you're stuck on the notion that SDL should help you constrain the frame rate. It doesn't do that; the frame rate is entirely up to you to manage. SDL will tell you what time it is (with `SDL_GetTicks()`. And to manage the frame rate, you need to know what time it is.

Answer (score 3):

Most game engines don't require asynchronous rendering, you typically have a loop where you update then render (more practically you have a fixed number of updates and a dynamic number of renders). [SDL_WaitEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent) is blocking and probably isn't what you want. You probably want [SDL_PollEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) which is non blocking. You typically keep polling events until there are no more events.

The general loop looks something like

```
void gameLoop()
{
    while(true)
    {
        update();
        render();
    }
}
```

and you would have your update function be something like

```
void update()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        // Handle Event
    }
    // Other Update Logic
}
```

This will keep calling polling events until there are no more in the queue, at which point [SDL_PollEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) returns 0 thus ending the event loop. From there you can go on to perform other update logic that isn't dependent on system events.

Comment: Could I have the main game loop sleep for 16 ms (60fps) each iteration? That wouldn't mess with the event system yes?

Comment: @Skits you'll get accumulated events on next frame.